# Hibernate :saving child entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

i have 2 tables:

Parent table:**phasesetups**

```
| id  | created             | modified            | name                                            | model | model_id | uid  | description      | old_model_id |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+------+------------------+--------------+
| 556 | 2016-08-26 14:08:07 | 2016-08-26 14:08:07 | EQ: 1  |  PREP: 2  |  ANALYSIS: 3  |  BIOINF: 4 | Order |        0 | uid  | first phasesetup | ng_2004741   |
```

Child table: **phases**

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| id   | created             | modified            | name | duration  | phasesetup_id | phasetype_id |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| 2263 | 2016-08-26 14:08:07 | 2016-08-26 14:08:07 | NULL | 345600000 |          NULL |            4 |
| 2266 | 2016-08-26 14:08:07 | 2016-08-26 14:08:07 | NULL |  86400000 |          NULL |            1 |
| 2269 | 2016-08-26 14:08:07 | 2016-08-26 14:08:07 | NULL | 172800000 |          NULL |            2 |
| 2272 | 2016-08-26 14:08:07 | 2016-08-26 14:08:07 | NULL | 259200000 |          NULL |            3 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
```

My entites:
1.PhaseSetup

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "phasesetups")
public class PhaseSetup extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column(name = "model_id")
    private Long modelId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "old_model_id")
    private String oldModelId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String uid;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "phasesetup_id", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<Phase> phases;
```

2nd Phases:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "phases")
public class Phase extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "phasetype_id")
    private Phasetype phasetype;

    private Long phasesetup_id;

    private Long duration;
```

**Problem:**     i want to save phases along with phasesetups and i am able to save them but phasesetup_id is still null.

Is not phasesetup_id supposed to be saved automatically ?as it is mappedby phasesetup_id ?

Please help me what am i missing here ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You donot require `private Long phasesetup_id;` in `Phase`. Change PhaseSetup as follows

```
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "phasesetup_id", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<Phase> phases;
```

to

```
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinColumn(name = "phasesetup_id")
private Set<Phase> phases;
```

You do not require mappedBy in unidirectional JPA relationships.Read [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany)

Comment: still phasesetup_id in phases is missing.

Comment: Could you share code snippet where you are persisting these entities?and what is your Id generation strategy for both entities?

Answer (score 0):

There is need to define relationship between PhaseSetups and Phase in Phase Entity. So define phasesetup_id in Phase as object like

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "`phasesetup_id`", referencedColumnName = "`uid`", insertable = true, updatable = true)
private PhaseSetup phasesetup;

I think, It will resolve your problem.